# In Endgame, why is the female leading the dance, and not the male?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

So, in the last scene of *Avengers: Endgame*, where

> Captain America flashes back to his trip to the past to return the Infinity Stones to their rightful places in space-time,

he dances with

> Peggy, his past [romance-partner thingy].

The two characters being respectively referred to as X and Y.

In that scene, it is clear that X and Y are dancing backwards. That is, Y's right arm is clearly visible on X's back, meaning that Y's left arm is extended outwards. Therefore, Y is the leading partner in the dance. However, traditionally, this general style of dance has the male partner lead, which is inconsistent with Y (female) leading the dance.

*I can't get that (horrible quality) leaked video into the question without spoilers, but I was just using it to show what scene anyway. I've seen the movie, and I'm pretty sure that I remember which person was where, but an image would be appreciated if one exists.*

What's going on here? Why are the two dancing backwards? Am I just blind? Is this a mistake? Is there a reason why this occurs?

Comment: maybe not answer-worthy, but in the first movie in which they discuss the dance for the first time, they clearly state that Y has danced before, while X never danced (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbpCqCZRj0U). If this is their first dance, it would make sense that she is teaching him how to do that.

Comment: @close-voters Okay people, you can't just click the next best close-reason your mouse is over. If you think the question is nitpicky, useless, irrelevant, or opinionated because the asker just doesn't know how dancing works, you'll have to say so. There's enough close-reasons for all of these things and enough room to explain in a custom close-reason, too. But if anything, it's quite *clear* what he wants to know here. I have reopened the question accordingly.

Comment: I might remember it incorrectly, but don't think anyone was leading, instead they were holding each other tight while dancing

Comment: Wonderful observation! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As established in Captain America: The First Avenger:

- Steve Rogers has never had a dance
- Steve Rogers does not know how to dance

Since Steve hasn't had the opportunity to learn how to dance since, I would expect this is still the case so Peggy is leading because she knows how to dance.

Comment: good answer, I like this one.